# The SQL Server Express stopped working after restart system

Tags: sql, sql-server

After restart system I try to connect to SQL Server Express, but I get an error; then I open services and try to start `SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)` service manually but I get another error

> The dependency service or group failed to start

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

1. Change the startup account of both the MSSQLSERVER and SQLServerAgent to use the local system account.
2. Restart the server.